# Understanding ORACLE'S BETWEEN Keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I was helping a co-worker debug a query that was returning weird results. We narrowed it down to a line that looked like this:

WHERE COL BETWEEN '11201' AND '111226'

The value in COL comes from a call to substring, so it's a string type value. This returns no results.

Naively, I had always assumed that BETWEEN represented >= and <= and that if you call it with strings, it would cast everything to numerical type values. That works just fine if you have something like:

WHERE COL BETWEEN '11201' AND '11226'

Which returns results in the case we are using it.

Clearly, since the second snippet returns results but the first snippet does not, my understanding is mistaken.

I cast everything to numbers and tried it again, and got the expected behavior. From this, it seems like I can conclude that when it does string comparisons, it actually *doesn't* cast the values - instead, it goes character by character. When it gets to the third character and sees 2 > 1 in the lower bound argument, it quits based on the following behavior from the [Oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147):

If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty.

Can anyone weigh in on if this is what is truly happening beneath the hood?

Thank you!

Comment: `col` is a string, and you're passing two strings into `between`.  I'm not sure why you would expect this to cast, but, as you've noticed, it does not.

Comment: @Donnie Yes, I really don't know why I would assume that it would cast - it seems quite silly in retrospect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
WHERE COL BETWEEN '11201' AND '111226'
```

is the same as:

```
WHERE COL >= '11201' AND COL <= '111226'
```

This returns nothing because -- as strings -- '11201' > '111226'. This uses alphabetic ordering, so this would be clearer if you used letters:

```
WHERE COL BETWEEN 'BBCAB' AND 'BBBCCG'
```

Clearly, there is nothing alphabetic between these values, because `'BBC'` occurs *after* `'BBB'`.

The moral?  If you want comparisons that are intuitive, use the right types.

Comment: That matches with what I hypothesized in the lower part of the question after I tested it, so I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Joe - The "Moral" at the end of Gordon's Reply is worth more than its weight in gold. What that means is not "wrap COL within TO_NUMBER". Rather, what it does mean is "make COL a column of NUMBER data type". There are many reasons for this. For example if you have an index on COL, and you mean COL to be numeric but you declare it as string, you will not able to use the index - so queries that should be almost instantaneous may instead run for a few minutes. Wrong data types is probably the most common abuse in Oracle (and in programming in general).

Answer (score 2):

In the expression below

```
WHERE COL BETWEEN '11201' AND '111226'
```

You are comparing a text column `COL` against text.  The string `'11201'` is lexicographically greater than the string `'111226'`.  In other words, `'11201'` comes *after* `'111226'` in the dictionary, or the former is *greater* than the latter.  This is why no results are coming back.  However, if you cast `COL` to a number, and compare that to numbers, then the comparison might work, assuming there are matching records:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER(COL) BETWEEN 11201 AND 111226
```